# Explicitly state input box is not for usernames/logins

Tags: html, css

Chrome is autofilling a box on a form on a website with the login username and when you submit the form it asks to save the login.

How can I force Chrome to leave the input field alone?

It's trying to be too smart for its own good.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="(Optional)" name="auth_code" />
```

It auto-fills with the login username:

[image]

EDIT:
I tried adding

```
autocomplete="off"
```

But the field still auto-fills with the login username on page load.

Another note:

I already have

```
value=""
```

But Chrome still auto-fills it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Doesn't that remove the suggestion dropdown? I still need that. I want the value itself to be empty on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#TheInput').val('');

    setTimeout(function () {

       $('#TheInput').val('');

    }, 100);
});
```

This code runs twice, just in case there's a browser-specific issue. It will definitely clear the input and requires jQuery, which may or may not be an issue for you. I also added an ID to reference the input element.

```
<input id="TheInput" type="text" placeholder="(Optional)" name="auth_code" />
```

Comment: Thanks I added some custom JS to sort it. Unfortunately it does flash for a second with the auto-fill before being empty. Bloody Chrome!!! Thanks

Comment: If it flashes, you can also hide it with css display:none so that it's not initially visible and then you change the js to $('#TheInput').val('').show() so that it will first clear then input and then display it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `autocomplete="off"`

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="(Optional)" name="auth_code" />
```

Comment: I added this but it isn't stopping the input from being filled automatically on page load.

Comment: clean your cache first

Comment: It wasn't caching. Chrome ignores the autocomplete attribute, I just looked it up. Thanks for your help anyway